# jquery datatables: render image from blob url

Tags: datatables, render

In a datatables column I want to display an image. The image is generated by sending the cell data to a 3rd party API that requires a POST request and returns a raw/binary png image.

What works just fine outside of datatables is:

```
// jquery ajax call. data is binary/raw png image
success: function ( data ) {
    var image = document.getElementById(image_tag_id)        
    var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    image.src = url.createObjectURL(data);
}
```

This is inside a function that takes the image tags id and the data as arguments. Previously I used the tag (HTMLElement) directly but changed it to the id to play with datatables `render` function.

This change actually makes what I want theoretically work (came up while writing this question) with below render function:

```
"render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
   if (type==="display") {
       var tag_id = "image-" + meta.row;
       getImage(tag_id, data);
       return '<img id="' + tag_id + '">';
   } else {
       return data;
   }
}
```

But this has a race condition. It assumes the returned html string always generates the tag faster than the image is fetched via ajax call (which probably always is the case but it I don't like it)

So how can I solve this issue better? Have render only create image tags and do the rest after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of getting the image in `render`, one can simply create a empty image tag with a class set. Then in `drawCallback` function, iterate over all the generated image tags and get the image via ajax call. This ensures there is no race condition.

However I went a different way and made my own service that works with GET requests. This then allows to set the src attribute of the image tags like one normally would. On top of that the images also can be cached and the source data for the image doesn't need to be transferred to the web page.